# Nginx behaves differently with the same site configuration in different docker images

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

```
nginx site config
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;
    gzip_static on;

    location ~* \.(html)$ {
        add_header 'X-XSS-Protection' '1';
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

it works perfect with docker image `node:14.19.3` (`nginx/1.14.2`), but with `node:14-alpine` (`nginx/1.22.1`) it behaves differently:

- trying accessing `index.html` (or `/`) redirects to default `/var/lib/nginx/index.html` (renders "Welcome to Nginx!"), though `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` exists and with permissions everything is OK
- if copy `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.txt`  - it is opened (`http://<<mydomain>/index.txt`)
- if copy `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/i.html`  - 404 - not found (`http://<<mydomain>/i.html`, well, it just can't find it in `/var/lib/nginx/i.html`)
- if remove the upper `location` block from the site config everything works perfect (there is just no that extra response header)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your configuration you define a regex location for `.html` files:

```
location ~* \.(html)$ {
    add_header 'X-XSS-Protection' '1';
}
```

This location is used by nginx for `.html` files, either directly requested as in `/index.html` or `/i.html`, or after an internal redirect to an index file (when `/` is internally redirected to `/index.html`).

There is no `root` directive in this location, and also no `root` directive at the `server` level. So the document root will be either inherited from `http` level, or, if there isn't any, the default document root will be used (`html` in the prefix directory). The difference between containers seems to be the `root /var/lib/nginx;` used at the `http` level in the non-working one, so the `/var/lib/nginx/index.html` is used for requests to `/index.html`.

In contrast, requests to `/index.txt` are handled in the `location /`, since there is no specific location matching `.txt` files. In this location your configuration explicitly defines `root`:

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    ...
}
```

Therefore `/index.txt` is mapped to `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.txt` regardless of other settings, so you are able to access it in your tests.

If you want all locations in the particular server to use the same document root, the most simple solution would be to define the `root` directive at the `server` level. For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location ~* \.(html)$ {
        add_header 'X-XSS-Protection' '1';
    }

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

For additional information please see nginx documentation:

- [location directive](http://nginx.org/r/location)
- [root directive](http://nginx.org/r/root)
- [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)